# What is the difference between emere and coemere?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison, gaius-iulius-caesar, bellum-gallicum, compound-verb

I was reading Caesar's *De Bello Gallico 1.3.1*, and I was curious why he used the word *coemere* when *emere* also seemed possible; which got me wondering, what exactly is the difference between the two words?

> His rebus adducti et auctoritate Orgetorigis permoti constituerunt ea quae ad proficiscendum pertinerent comparare, iumentorum et carrorum quam maximum numerum **coemere**, sementes quam maximas facere, ut in itinere copia frumenti suppeteret, cum proximis civitatibus pacem et amicitiam confirmare.
>
> Having been led by these things, and roused by the influence of Orgetorix, they decided to place together those things which pertain to departure, **to purchase** as great a number as possible of baggage animals and wagons, to do as much planting as possible, so that they would have a supply of grain available on the journey, and to make peace and friendship with the neighboring clans.

I'm reproducing the text (and my translation) to provide some context, and I hope it's helpful instead of distracting. Anyway, I suspect that *coemere* might be an intensified form of *emere*, but if this is true then I'm not sure how it intensifies the meaning of the base verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Emere* would indeed be possible, but the prefix *co-* adds a flavor which suits this situation well.
It is not intensified, but rather toned.
I might translate *coemere* as "to collect by buying" or "to buy up".
When buying everything needed for a long journey, I would use *coemere* instead of *emere*.
Latin is redundant here: the fact that it is more *coemere* than *emere* is also indicated by the sentence as a whole.

As far as I know, you cannot make the same distinction in English as easily.
Your translation with "purchase" looks good; the context conveys the meaning the Latin prefix *co-* does so there is no need for translating it.